# why android takes so long to start up?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, boot

I met a strange problem when i started up a android device. Below is the log i got from the console port. I found it took **more than 4 minutes** for function **rknand_buffer_thread** executed. But before with the same device, it only takes only **10 seconds**. Is there anyone meeting this issue? Why it happens and what this function is used for? My android version is 4.2.

> [ 13.430222] init: sys_prop: permission denied uid:1003 name:media.cfg.audio.soundeffect
>
> [ 17.935034] warning: `zygote' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
>
> [ 26.592006] rknand_buffer_thread write data begin 224000 0
>
> [ 278.908582] request_suspend_state: wakeup (3->0) at 278857509285 (2000-01-01 00:04:56.640167033 UTC)
>
> [ 280.226573] Current WiFi chip is AP6210. [ 280.232740] init: no such service 'dhcpcd_'

Answer (score -1):

Finally I got the reason. Because i called a API function which needs WAN, so it retrys all the time during android starting up.